# In Visual Code (mac) is there a way to start at the second placeholder on a snippet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets, usability

I love to use snippets in the form of:

```
println("MyVariable:" + MyVariable);
```

So I end up creating snippets like this:

```
SnippetBody:[ "printlns(\"$1:\" + $1);" ]
```

The problem is that I want the focus on the second $1 so the intellisense triggers. Since the focus is on the first $1 and it's a string, then there is no intellisense.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want is for autocomplete to work on strings, you can look at the settings and set:

```
"editor.quickSuggestions": {
        "other": true,
        "comments": false,
        "strings": true
    }
```

Then you start typing and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to trigger the list.

Comment: This is not the perfect solution but good enough considering the perfect solution will never be implemented.

Comment: When I do this I get much poorer intellisense than simply with no string involved.  Moreover, a couple of fixes I tried showed that accepting a suggestion by tab completely messes up the snippet tab traversal.  I'll probably file an issue.